# Jsjws JSON Web signatures and tokens

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I'm trying to include jsjws in my current project (Backbone, Marionette) which uses RequireJS to include all modules. I have AMD and non AMD scripts included, the non AMD using shims but I'm not sure how jsjws (http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/) will work in this instance. Maybe someone can help?

Current RequireJS config with attempt at including jsjws:

```
    paths: {
    backbone: "vendor/backbone", "backbone.syphon":"vendor/backbone.syphon",
    jquery: "vendor/jquery",
    json2: "vendor/json2",
    underscore: "vendor/underscore",
    marionette: "vendor/backbone.marionette",
    jsjws: "vendor/jws-3.0",
    tpl: "vendor/tpl"
},

shim: {
    underscore: {
        exports: "_"
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: ["jquery", "underscore", "json2"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    },
    "backbone.syphon": ["backbone"],
    marionette: {
        deps: ["backbone"],
        exports: "Marionette"
    }
}
```

many thanks,

Wittner

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code for jsws and at the documentation, it seems to me that this is what you need to add to your shims:

```
jsjws: {
    exports: "KJUR"
}
```

Or I believe you could have it export `"KJUR.jws"` to skip the top level namespace (which seems useless in this context).

I was not able to find a clear list of what dependencies it has. If I look at the various samples in the github repo, the list of files loaded before jsjws seems to vary quite a bit depending on the specific needs of the project. At any rate, whatever *your* project needs for jsjws to do its job would have to be added to a `deps` field, and probably these dependencies would get shims of their own.

Comment: Thanks for this Louis. I will try and implement my solution this way and get back to you